# HTMX event is not triggered on pickadate.js selection

Tags: jquery, django, htmx, pickadate

I use `django-forms-dynamic` package and htmx to dynamically load available options on a `MultipleChoiceField`. The options are based on a date field, for which I use `pickadate.js` by Amsul.

I updated the code. So, the initial query gets the correct choices from the database. However, if the date is changed, the 'change' event is not fired. Also, I tried to manually trigger the htmx event. Without success

**reservation_form.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-floating">
    {% render_field reservation_form.date class="datepicker form-control mb-3" 
           hx-get="/reservation/filter-seats" 
           hx-include="#id_dinner" 
           hx-trigger="click change" 
           hx-target="#id_seat_reservation" 
    %}
    <label for="id_date">Dinner Date</label>
  </div>


  <div class="form-floating">
    {% render_field reservation_form.amount_guests class+="form-control" placeholder="" %}
    <label for="id_amount_guests">Guests</label>
  </div>

  <div class="visually-hidden">
    {% render_field reservation_form.dinner %}
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    {% render_field reservation_form.seat_reservation class+="form-select" %}
    <label for="id_seat_reservation">Select Seats</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**pickadate script**

```
<script>
    var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                        min: 0,
                        max: 90,
                        disable: {{ blocked_dates }},
                        firstDay: 1,

                        onOpen: function() {
                            // Get the hidden input field
                            var hiddenInput = $(this.$node).siblings('[name="date_submit"]');
                            // Add HTMX attributes to the hidden input field
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-trigger', 'change');
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-get', "{% url 'filter-seats' %}");
                            hiddenInput.attr('hx-target', '#modal-xl');
                        }
    });

    $input.on('change', function() {
        var hiddenInput = $(this).siblings('[name="date_submit"]');
        hiddenInput.val($(this).val());
        htmx.trigger(hiddenInput[0], 'change');
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the triggers as `hx-trigger="click change"`. First, this is incorrect, you have to separate events with a comma, right now HTMX tries to evaluate `change` as a trigger modifier without success. Therefore you only have the `click` trigger event, HTMX submits the form when you click on the input element. At the same time `pickadate.js` also listens to the click event and opens the datepicker widget. After selecting a date the form dispatches the `change` event, but you have disabled that for HTMX so it will not submit the form again. Next time you click on the input element HTMX submits the form with the previously selected value.

To fix the issue just remove the `hx-trigger` attribute. For input fields the [default trigger is already the `change` event](https://htmx.org/docs/#triggers), therefore HTMX will submit the form when `pickadate.js` enters the selected date into the input field.

Comment: Initially, I tried it without the hx-trigger. However, it doesn't do anything in conjunction with pickadate.js. So, I inserted the hx-trigger.

Comment: Any idea, how to solve this ussue? It doesn't work with and without hx-trigger.